# Splitting a list on non-sequential numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have an ordered list of entities, numbered in a broken sequence:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 17, 18, 19]
```

I'd like to break the list where there's a gap, and collect the results in a new list:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7], [11], [17, 18, 19]]
```

I have the feeling there's a name for what I want to do and probably a nice library function for it -  but I can't think of it. Can anyone shine some light before I possibly reinvent a wheel?

---

edit: Thanks, folks, but I was asking if there's a name for this operation and an existing algorithm, not for implementations - this is what I came up with:

```py
def group_adjoining(elements, key=lambda x: x):
    """Returns list of lists of contiguous elements

    :key: function to get key integer from list element
    """
    if not elements:
        return elements

    result = [[elements[0]]]

    for a, b in zip(elements, elements[1:]):
        if key(a) + 1 == key(b):
            result[-1].append(b)
        else:
            result.append([b])

    return result
```

Comment: `for a, b in zip(mylist, mylist[1:])` comes to mind

Comment: Could you try using np.diff to calculate the differences, then using that to find the indexes where it's more than one?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping to avoid requiring a numpy dependency

Comment: I don't think there is a special function for that but "itertools.groupby" should help with an appropriate key function.

Comment: The external library "more_itertools" has a function to make it even easier: https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_when The example is nearly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain `itertools.groupby` approach:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 17, 18, 19]

out = []
for _, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda x: x[0] - x[1]):
    out.append([v for _, v in g])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7], [11], [17, 18, 19]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try greedy approach:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 17, 18, 19]
res = []
tmp = []
prv = lst[0]
for l in lst:
    if l-prv > 1:
        res.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    tmp.append(l)
    prv = l
res.append(tmp)
print(res)
```

Output: `[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7], [11], [17, 18, 19]]`

Answer (score 3):

I first came across [more_itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) today, and I think this package is useful for this problem.

`pip install more-itertools`

```
from more_itertools import split_when

l = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 17, 18, 19]
res = list(split_when(l, lambda a, b: a + 1 != b))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple generator.

```
def split(lst):
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        if (not result) or result[-1] + 1 == item:
            result.append(item)
        else:
            yield result
            result = [item]
    if result:
        yield result


foo = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 17, 18, 19]
result = [i for i in split(foo)]
print(result) # [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7], [11], [17, 18, 19]]
```

This assumes a sorted homogeneous `list` of `int`.

You could always avoid the sorted assumption with `for item in sorted(lst):`.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy by using this simple function:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18]

def split(li):
    result = []
    temp = [li[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(li)):
        if li[i] - temp[-1] == 1:
            temp.append(li[i])
        else:
            result.append(temp)
            temp = [li[i]]
    result.append(temp)
    return result

print(split(li))
```